# How to redirect anonymous user to 404 instead of 403?

Tags: 7, users, redirection

I'm new to Drupal so am struggling here. I've created a checkbox field and the goals is that when it is checked it redirects anonymous to the 404 page.

I have the following condition:

```
function page_module_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

 // code to retrive checkbox value

 if (user_is_anonymous() && $page_hidden_value == 1) {
    drupal_not_found();
  }
}
```

But this doesnt work.

However, interestingly enough if I do the reverse and check that the user is logged in (`!user_is_anonymous()`) it does work and does redirect to 404.

I can DPM the value of the checkbox (`$page_hidden_value`) so I know that's working correctly.

Would anyone know what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I have had some odd experiences with `user_is_anonymous()`. Try using negation with `user_is_logged_in()`. For example:

```
if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of got this working with `drupal_goto`

```
 if (user_is_anonymous() && $page_hidden_value == 1) {
    drupal_goto('/404');
  }
```